# Using @PreserveOnRefresh (Vaadin 7), can I have a listener called for each "reinit" within a UIDL request?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

When a user comes back to their session I have a listener check for some get parameters (denoting authentication). The problem is I can't reinitialize UI logic from that point (I believe) because it's not within a UIDL transaction. At any rate, my UI throws as NPE as soon as it hits the first call for UI.getCurrent().

How can I get a safe hook into each page refresh?

Answer (score 2):

Vaadin 7.2 introduced a method called `refresh(VaadinRequest)` in `UI` which is called after a browser refresh when the `UI` has the `@PreserveOnRefresh` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to find a simple 'refresh' listener, but managed to get the behaviour by combining a RequestHandler and a UriFragmentChangedListener.

```
ui.getPage().addUriFragmentChangedListener(new Page.UriFragmentChangedListener() {        
    @Override
    public void uriFragmentChanged(final Page.UriFragmentChangedEvent event) {
        // ...proceed with application setup
    }
});

ui.getSession().addRequestHandler(new RequestHandler() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(VaadinSession session, VaadinRequest request, VaadinResponse response) {
        if (containsAuthInfo(request)) {
            final String redirect = "<html><body></body><script>window.location=\"" 
                + APP_URL + "#" + UUID.randomUUID() + "\";</script></body></html>";
            response.getOutputStream().write(redirect.getBytes());
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```